# RCC Manager issue in react-native-navigation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to implement the react-native-navigation tab bar in a react native project, although I keep getting the error:

> 'undefined is not an object(Evaluating RCCManager.setRootController)'.

I first installed react-native-navigation, then react-native-controllers, then did react-native link (just like the tutorial says).

Here is my AppDelegate.m code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RCCManager.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings]jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [[RCCManager sharedInstance] initBridgeWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too. Did you figure it out?